# angularjs ng-repeat - add an anchor to jump from top to bottom and bottom to top

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the ng-repeat to iterate over an array that sometimes may be over a thousand records. I was wondering if there was a way to add some type of anchor to the first record (last in list) so I can get to it without scrolling down thru all the records. Here is my code:

```
<div  ng-repeat="emps in Savedcontacts">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="infoRapper_c">
                        <div class="infoRapper-pad_c">



                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="phonetd1_c ">
                                        <p>{{emps.F_NAME}} {{emps.L_NAME}} </p>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone mylittlephone_c"> </span> <a class="phoneNumber_c" href="tel:{{emps.PHONE}}"> {{emps.PHONE|cleanPhoneNum}}</a>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="phonetd2_c">
                                        <!-- table inside <td>  -->
                                        <table>
                                            <tr class="phonetd2_table_tr1_c"><td class="phonetd2_table_td1_c">{{$index + 1}}</td></tr>
                                            <tr class="phonetd2_table_tr2_c"><td ng-click="getLocalDetails('/employeesLocalDetails/' + emps.USERID)" class="phonetd2_table_td2_c">>>></td></tr>
                                            <tr class="phonetd2_table_tr3_c"><td class="phonetd2_table_td3_c"></td></tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer"><hr /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight) - will take you to the bottom of page - will that help?

Comment: Does adding a regular anchor tag here not do the trick? Is this onclick you want it to go to bottom of page?

Comment: Have you tried using `$first` and `$last`?

Answer (score 0):

You have an example in the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

```
<button ng-click="goToBottom()">Go to last</button>
<div id="bloc{{$index}}" ng-repeat="bloc in data">Bloc {{bloc}}</div>
```

Ctrl:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

  $scope.goToBottom = function () {
    // scroll to last id
    $anchorScroll('bloc' + ($scope.data.length -1));
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HpEufzZzF2yYBnY1xdeG?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but adding these to the body of the `ng-repeat` loop may do the trick:

```
<a id="top" ng-if="$first">Top</a>
<a id="bottom" ng-if="$last">Bottom"</a>

<span ng-if="$first" onclick="#bottom">Click to go to bottom</span>
<span ng-if="$last"  onclick="#top">Click to go to top</span>
```

The `<a>` elements create anchors at the top (first) and bottom (last) items in the list, and the `<span>` elements create clickable labels to navigate to those items.